# cellForRowAtIndexPath always returns last cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uicollectionview

I have `tableView` in `colletionViewCell` and I am also using `UILongPressGesture`on my `collectionView`.

**What I am trying to achieve:**

1. Detect long press. (Done)
2. Decide if longPress is on `collectionViewCell` or `tableViewCell` (colectionViewCell also have empty space i.e space which is not covered by tableView) (Done)
3. Take the screen shot of the `collectionViewCell` if long press is on collectionView (not on tableView or tableViewCell) (Done).
4. Take the screen shot of the `tableViewCell` if long press is on tableView **(Not done)**

**Whats Going wrong:**
Cell returned by tableView for indexPath is always wrong. Below is my code step by step.

Get index path of collectionViewCell from longPress `locationInView:`

```
CGPoint collectionPoint = [longPressGesture locationInView:_collectionView];
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [_collectionView indexPathForItemAtPoint:collectionPoint];
```

Get collectionViewCell using

```
ColumnCollectionViewCell *cell = (ColumnCollectionViewCell*)[_collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```

This return correct collectionViewCell

Find indexPath for tableViewCell using

```
NSIndexPath *cardIndexPath = [cell.cardsTableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:[_collectionView convertPoint:collectionPoint toView:cell.cardsTableView]];
```

This returns 100% correct indexPath. I have tested number of cases.indexPath is always what it needs to be.

But when I do

```
UITableViewCell *cardCell = [cell.cardsTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```

This return me wrong tableViewCell.

**Important :** I have two different Custom tableViewCells. Lets CustomCell1 and CustomCell2

Only and only last cell in tableView will be of type CustomCell2. And this is the cell returned always no matter what.

For Example: If I pass indexPath where `row is 1 and section is 0`, visually its CustomCell1(and should be) but returned cell is CustomCell2 which is actually at indexPath`(row = 3 section = 0`).

Comment: Did you mean to write `cardIndexPath` in your code snippet for `cellForRowAtIndexPath`? Is it the same in your code?

Comment: thanks @Mats. I think I should get a cup of coffee before doing any further work